# How can I wrap php errors in html tags?

Tags: php

I have a site that has an absolutely positioned navigation bar that sits at the top of the window, so that when I scroll down the page, the rest of the content goes underneath it.

The site is currently in its "testing" phase and there is the occasional php error that appears on the page. Unfortunately, it appears at the top of the code and is therefore showing at the top of the window which is visually covered by the absolutely positioned navigation bar. I myself could use the inspector to hide the navigation bar to see what the error message reads that is underneath the nav bar, but the other users I have testing the site do not know how to do that.

I would like to wrap the php errors that are output in custom html tags which I can then give a higher z-index to so it appears above the navigation bar. Then, the users can report to me what the exact php error is that is displayed to them.

How can I wrap my php errors in html tags?

Comment: What you've really after is the error messages. Why make the users send them to you if you can do that programatically?

Comment: Why can't you just log errors instead??

Comment: I am actually logging all the errors but I am receiving emails from some of the testers that the page is blank except for the the navigation bar. This leads me to believe that the fatal error is appearing underneath the navigation bar and then stopping the rest of the page from loading. Unfortunately, when I check the error logs I don't see any reference to an error on that specific page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own error handler as such: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

This will let you control how the error is outputted. In your case:

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    } 

    echo "<p class="error">ERROR: [$errno] $errstr <br />\n";
    echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile </p>";
}
```

Should work?

Also, if you want to log the fatal errors, use this;

```
function shutdownFunction() { 
    $error = error_get_last(); 
    if ($error['type'] == 1) { 
        // fatal error logging goes here
    } 
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction');
```